# Msg 4861, Level 16, State 1, Line 1, could not be opened. Operating system error code 3(The system cannot find the path specified.)

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert

I have problem in bulk insert, please anyone help me

> Msg 4861, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot bulk load because the file "D:\BESTTA 7\20200518_DLLD_3C.txt" could not be opened. Operating system error code 3 (The system cannot find the path specified)

This is my SQL statement:

```
BULK INSERT LLD2017_26032020.dbo.TRX_TRANSAKSI_3C
FROM 'D:\\BESTTA 7\20200518_DLLD_3C.txt' --location with filename
WITH
(
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '|',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO

SELECT *
FROM TRX_TRANSAKSI_3C ttt 
WHERE jenis_rekening = '3C' 
  AND ttt.TGL_TRANSAKSI = '20200518'
```

Comment: Why are you mixing ``\\`` and ``\`` in the same string literal?

Comment: Are you sure that file exists on the **database server**?

Comment: I think, it's all done, thanks alll.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means, the SQL Server is not able to find the path. Are you having this file in the SQL Server machine ? If you are having this in your local server and running from SSMS client, SQL Server will not be checking this in your local machine.

> 'D:\BESTTA 7\20200518_DLLD_3C.txt' --location with filename

The above path **SHOULD** be present in the **SQL Server server machine, local folder**, **NOT** in your **local machine, local folder**

Comment: thanks venkataraman, its right, and i fix it about it..

Comment: @griyacode, cool. welcome